# Why is my insert query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['create_post']))
    {
        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $post_author = $_POST['post_author'];
        $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category_id'];
        $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
        $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
        $post_date = date('d-m-y');
        $post_comment_count = 4;


        move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../image/ $post_image");

        $query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status) ";

        $query .= "Values ( $post_category_id, '$post_title', '$post_author',now(), '$post_image', '$post_content', '$post_tags', '$post_comment_count', '$post_status') ";

        $connet_query_post = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$connet_query_post)
        {

            die("Query Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }



    }

?>

<h1 class="page-header">
                        Wellcome to Admin
                        <small>author</small>
                    </h1>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_category">Post Category Id </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_category_id" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_author">Post Author </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_author">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_status">Post Status </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_status" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post Tags </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_tags" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_content">Post Contents</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post Tags </label>
        <input type="text" name="create_post" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Publish" name="create_post" >
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the form which i'm dealing with, I'm getting an error thats is

> Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '',now(), '', '', '', '4', '')' at line 1

i have checked my query it looks correct according to me

Comment: what is output of echo $query ?
can you please put it original output of echo $query ?

Comment: you have a problem with the values you are inserting in your query. Show a sample query replacing variables with real data. Also note that you are open to SQL Injections since you are not sanitizing your data. Learn about prepared statements since you are still learning

Comment: @Ankitvadariya i am working on admin Panel so i have created a form, trying to fill it but it is showing errors that i can not understand how to remove the concept is filling forms and then it must submit to database

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you specify all fields to while executing insert query? If not, then you have to specify explictly all fields before VALUES so that it work.
like INSERT INTO Table t (t2,t3,t4) VALUES(.....) while in real table more than specified columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using apostrophe in one of php variables. Use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp) function on each of variables you get from form. You should do it always because of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

What are the column types you are using for these

"post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status".

Also use mysqli_real_escape_string() for strings, you need to pass active connection as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../image/ $post_image");

$query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status) ";

 $query .= "Values ( $post_category_id, '$post_title', '$post_author','".now()."', '$post_image', '$post_content', '$post_tags', '$post_comment_count', '$post_status') ";

$connet_query_post = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

          if(!$connet_query_post)
            {

                die("Query Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
            }
```

now() is the function you can't use it as string.

```
Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', '',now(), '', '', '', '4', '')' at line 1
```

in your error you can see now() instated of now() there should be some value in string

Comment: What kind of value i am watching tutorial, instructor has done same he has not passed any value

Comment: just replace  now() with '".now()."' and try

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function now() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 18

Comment: please replace now() with date('Y-m-d')

Comment: Actually I have used that function While collecting Data from forms if i am not using now instead there is an error